# How to add two checkbox values together?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have these checkboxes:

```
<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ol>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1"> 1</p>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="2" value="2"> 2</p>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="3" value="3"> 3</p>
  </ol>
  <button type="button" class="check">Submit</button>
```

How would I make clicking the submit button add the selected boxes together? Like if I had the 1 and 3 boxes checked, how would I add them together so I can print 4 or whatever combination of numbers onscreen?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free coding service. What did you try for yourself? You will need JavaScript for this problem, so what have you tried? What worked / didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:checked` selector to obtain all the checked boxes and then loop over all of them to sum their values.

```js
document.querySelector('button.check').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  const checked = document.querySelectorAll('ol input:checked');
  let sum = 0;
  checked.forEach(box => sum += +box.value);
  console.log(sum);
});
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1"> 1</p>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="2" value="2"> 2</p>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="3" value="3"> 3</p>
</ol>
<button type="button" class="check">Submit</button>
```